# What do you call 'be-to' constructions and are they acceptable English?

Tags: writing-style, register, infinitive-constructions, periphrastic-modals

Consider the following examples:

> You have to be really patient if you **are to go** shopping in the afternoon.
>   It must be active if it **is to record** the film.

What is the construction in bold typeface called and should it be used in formal English texts — is it good or bad style?

Comment: http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv103.shtml

Comment: @Gigili: Thanks for the link; that sheds some preliminary light on the issue.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/613772/2085).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the ***Be* + Infinitive Construction**, if you need a name. The construction is not limited to infinitive use; i.e, it's not just ***to*** be to + Infinitive. It can also be used in the present or past tense.

- *He is to leave tomorrow.*
- *He was to leave yesterday, but the flight was cancelled.*

A bare infinitive in a strange place, like after an auxiliary verb (e.g, *be* or *have*), is bound to be an idiom, and usually has a [modal](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/modals.html) meaning:

- *He has to leave*. (He **must** leave)
- *He is to leave*  (He **will** leave ~ He is expected/scheduled to leave)

just like relative infinitives (infinitive clauses modifying nouns) always have a modal meaning:

- *He is the man to see about this.*  (He is the man that one **should** see)
- *He is the man to do the job.*  (He is the man who **should** do it)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Still, my main concern was whether this was formal English in the stricter sense and fit for formal texts.

Comment: Yes, it's formal English. Any time you're talking about a schedule, you're being formal.

Comment: I agree, of course. But the question is not right: there is no to-be-to construction.

Comment: The questions are almost never right. There are usually false presuppositions that go uncorrected. Life is short and this service is free.

Answer (score 0):

If "He has to leave" is idiomatic, what is "He doesn't have to leave"? "Have to" plus bare infinitive is perfectly grammatical, I believe, especially after defective verbs.