# Meaning of the structure [be + to + verb] in this context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, literature, deontic-vs-epistemic, periphrastic-modals

I’m trying to understand the meaning of “whom they are to admire” in this long sentence:

> From these causes it results that the advocates of drastic reform divide themselves into opposing schools, hating each other with a bitter hatred, accusing each other often of such crimes as being in the pay of the police, and demanding, of any speaker or writer **whom they are to admire**, that he shall conform exactly to their prejudices, and make all his teaching minister to their belief that the exact truth is to be found within the limits of their creed. 
> ―[Bertrand Russell in *Roads to Freedom*](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Roads_to_freedom)

Does it mean *they do not admire a speaker or writer unless he/she conforms exactly to their prejudices*?